# Restangular addElementTransformer / extendModel for ALL routes

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How can I addElementTransformer for all models? I want all my models have extra method for delayed save, for example:

```
Restangular.extendModel('*', function(model){
    model.delayed_save = _.debounce(model.save, 1000, {maxWait: 5000})
}
```

But I need to make it for every route I have.
I know I can create factory for wrapping Restangular service with route parameter like this:

```
angular.module('app')
        .service('restangularService', restangularService)  
    function restangularService(Restangular) {
        var self = this;
        self.init = init

        function init(route) {
            Restangular.extendModel(route, function(model){
                model.deferred_save = _.debounce(model.save, 1000, {maxWait: 5 * 1000})
                return model
            })

            return Restangular.service(route)
        }
    }
```

and this will work, but I believe there have to be a better way

Answer (score 1):

I needed this to remove the parentResource after saving a nested resource so used setOnElemRestangularized:

```
RestangularConfigurer.setOnElemRestangularized(function(elem, isCollection, what, Restangular) {
    if (!isCollection && elem.fromServer && elem.parentResource) elem.parentResource = null;
    return elem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setOnElemRestangularized`](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setonelemrestangularized) to achieve this.

Something like this should work (untested)

```
.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setOnElemRestangularized(function(elem, isCollection, what, Restangular) {
        if (isCollection) { return; }
        console.log("Path: ", what);
        elem.newMethod = function() { console.log("TODO: Add code here..."); };
        return elem;
    });
})
```

Comment: The function should return the `elem` , otherwise you end up with an error when you create the services.